# What is the cartesian product of an empty set of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let  $$Y=\prod_{X\in \emptyset}X$$

What is $Y$? The empty set? The singleton set?

**EDIT**: Here is another way of reading the conclusion in the comments so far:

$Y$ is the set $$Y=\{(x_1,...,x_n) | x_1\in X_1,...,x_n\in X_n, \text{ for } X_1,...,X_n\in \emptyset\}$$

But the only tuple satisfying this is $()$, i.e. the empty tuple. Hence $Y$ is the singleton. **Is this argument correct?**

Comment: It has one element, and that element is the function whose domain is the empty set.

Comment: @bof, can you give me a function whose domain is the empty set? It seems to me that no such function exists.

Comment: @user56834 In set theory, a function $f : X \to Y$ is just a particular type of subset of $X \times Y$. So, a function whose domain and codomain are empty, if it existed, would be some subset of $\emptyset \times \emptyset = \emptyset$. But there is only one such subset: $\emptyset$. So that's the function they were referring to.

Comment: @ZeroXLR, see my edit. is this correct?

Comment: You should **not** think of elements of the general cartesian product as “tuples” (except in the special case of elements of a cartesian product of two sets, which is needed to define functions). It makes no sense for arbitrary index sets. The elements of the cartesian product are **functions** with domain the index set and codomain the union of the sets in. the family. Writing it as a tuple just re-phrases the problem, it does not solve it.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is the collection of all functions $f\colon I \to \cup_{i\in I}X_i$ such that for all $i\in I$, $f(i)\in X_i$.

Thus, by definition, your $Y$ is the collection of all functions $f\colon \varnothing \to \cup_{X\in\varnothing}X$ such that for all $X\in\varnothing$, $f(X)\in X$. But $\cup_{X\in\varnothing}X = \varnothing$. So you are looking for all functions $f\colon \varnothing\to\varnothing$ which satisfy a vacuous property.

Comment: There is exactly one function from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$ so we get a singleton set. Just like the empty product in a group is the unit element.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, see my edit. Is this correct?

Comment: @user56834 on what grounds is an empty tuple a singleton? Seems to replace the problem by another one.